# How to Get Video Lossless Rotation When Re-encoding Using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, lossless

I'm looking for how to rotate a video without losing any quality when re-encoding. I currently use `ffmpeg -i "inputvideo" -crf 0 -vf transpose=2 -acodec copy "outputvideo"`. Although `-crf 0` should be lossless, I found there is difference after comparing the first frame of the original video and the rotated video. What is the reason?

I noticed there is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535017/11081223 modifying hex data to achieve video rotation without re-encoding, but it does not change the actual file just the metadata only to let the player know. I assume that method leaves rotation job for player to deal with so the image quality difference is more obvious.

The screenshot is here. The left one is the original.

[image]

Comment: yes if you don't want to modify metadata then you'll need to actually rotate the image blocks, which might or might not be lossless, depending on whether the codec has anyway to calculate new coefficients that produce lossless output or not